# Untar *.tar.bz2 using 7-zip on windows command line

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7, 7zip, cppunit

I have a function in a powershell script that is supposed to untar my CppUnit.tar.bz2 file. I have installed 7-zip, and in my function I have the following:

```
Function untar ($targetFile) {        
        $z ="7z.exe"

        $defaultDestinationFolder = 'C:\Program Files\'
        $destinationFolder = (Get-Item $defaultDesitantionFolder).fullname

        $tarbz2Source = $targetFile
        & "$z" x -y $tarbz2Source

        $tarSource = (get-item $targetFile).basename
        & "$z" x -y $tarSource -o $destinationFolder

        Remove-Item $tarSource
}
```

Running this extracts all the files where I want them, BUT all the files get ",v" as their ending:

```
...
Extracting  cppunit-cvs-repo-archive\cppunit\cppunit\Attic
Extracting  cppunit-cvs-repo-archive\cppunit\cppunit\Attic\estring.h,v
Extracting  cppunit-cvs-repo-archive\cppunit\cppunit\Attic\TestSuite.h,v
Extracting  cppunit-cvs-repo-archive\cppunit\cppunit\Attic\Test.h,v
Extracting  cppunit-cvs-repo-archive\cppunit\cppunit\Attic\TestCase.h,v
Extracting  cppunit-cvs-repo-archive\cppunit\cppunit\Attic\TextTestResult.h,v
Extracting  cppunit-cvs-repo-archive\cppunit\cppunit\Attic\Makefile.am,v
Extracting  cppunit-cvs-repo-archive\cppunit\cppunit\Attic\TestSuite.cpp,v
Extracting  cppunit-cvs-repo-archive\cppunit\cppunit\Attic\Exception.cpp,v
Extracting  cppunit-cvs-repo-archive\cppunit\cppunit\Attic\cppunit.dsw,v
Extracting  cppunit-cvs-repo-archive\cppunit\cppunit\Attic\TestFailure.h,v
Extracting  cppunit-cvs-repo-archive\cppunit\cppunit\Attic\TestCaller.h,v
Extracting  cppunit-cvs-repo-archive\cppunit\cppunit\Attic\TestResult.h,v
Extracting  cppunit-cvs-repo-archive\cppunit\cppunit\Attic\TextTestResult.cpp,v
Extracting  cppunit-cvs-repo-archive\cppunit\cppunit\Attic\TestRegistry.h,v
Extracting  cppunit-cvs-repo-archive\cppunit\cppunit\Attic\TestFailure.cpp,v
Extracting  cppunit-cvs-repo-archive\cppunit\cppunit\Attic\Exception.h,v
Extracting  cppunit-cvs-repo-archive\cppunit\cppunit\Attic\TestRegistry.cpp,v
Extracting  cppunit-cvs-repo-archive\cppunit\cppunit\Attic\cppunit.dsp,v
Extracting  cppunit-cvs-repo-archive\cppunit\cppunit\Attic\TestResult.cpp,v
Extracting  cppunit-cvs-repo-archive\cppunit\cppunit\Attic\TestCase.cpp,v

Everything is Ok

Folders: 149
Files: 1128
Size:       20671974
Compressed: 21626880
```

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `,v` suffix indicates that these are not the files themselves, but version history files maintained by CVS - each `,v` file contains not only the latest version of the file, but the deltas to reconstruct any previous version of the file. The fact that they're all in an `Attic` subdirectory indicates that they were all removed via `cvs remove` at some point. These and the fact that the base directory is `cppunit-cvs-repo-archive` says you need to treat the unpacked archive as a CVS repository, and use the appropriate tools to check out the files you want to work with, not just "fix" what looks like wrong names...

Comment: Downloaded the correct cppunit package, ran the function and it's all good. :)